# I cannot use values claus with subquery?

Tags: insert, subquery

I need this information for my task. I can not use alternative. I know that I can use subquery like this:

```
insert into (select id from test) (select employee_id FROM employees);
```

But this is not what I want. I tasked to finde the answer to this question. Please help me. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Please type again what you have and what kind of alternative you want to retrieve.

Comment: That query does not make any sense - can you share more details, especially about the database system this should work on?

Answer (score 0):

You should use like the below without using values clause in INSERT

```
Insert into test 
select employee_id FROM employees;
```